# Creating cube with user input using three.js

Tags: three.js

I am trying to get a user input from a form and create a cube out of it.  Right now it doesn't update the image at all. This is also my first post on here so it's probably going to look like crap.
I'm looking to do this at runtime and have it change based off a single part of the from being changed one at a time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var Warehouse = {
        length: 4,
        width: 4,
        height: 4,
        columnBaySpacingL: 0,
        columnBaySpacingW: 0,
        exteriorConstruction: "",
        numberOfDockDoors: 0,
        squareFootage: 0,
        numberOfParkingSpc: 0
    };//end of warehouse object

    //create object

    Warehouse.length = myForm.elements["LOW"].value;
    Warehouse.width = myForm.elements["WOW"].value;
    Warehouse.height = myForm.elements["HOW"].value;
    Warehouse.columnBaySpacingL = myForm.elements["CBSL"].value;
    Warehouse.columnBaySpacingW = myForm.elements["CBSW"].value;
    Warehouse.exteriorConstruction = myForm.elements["EXT"].value;
    Warehouse.numberOfDockDoors = myForm.elements["NDD"].value;
    Warehouse.squareFootage = myForm.elements["SOA"].value;
    Warehouse.numberOfParkingSpc = myForm.elements["NPS"].value;

    //Warehouse.length = getElementsByName("LOW").value;
    //Warehouse.width = getElementById("WOW").value;
    //Warehouse.height = getElementById("HOW").value;
    //Global vars for Three.js
    var container, stats;

    var CANVAS_WIDTH = 200;
    var CANVAS_HEIGHT = 200;

    var camera, scene, renderer;

    var cube, plane;

    var targetRotation = 0;
    var targetRotationOnMouseDown = 0;

    var mouseX = 0;
    var mouseXOnMouseDown = 0;

    var windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
    var windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

    init(Warehouse);
    animate();

    //Three.js functions

    function init(Warehouse) {
        //container = document.createElement('div');
        container = document.getElementById('canvas');
        document.body.appendChild(container);

       // var info = document.createElement('div');
       // var info = document.getElementById('canvas');
       // info.style.position = 'absolute';
       // info.style.top = '10px';
       // info.style.width = '100%';
       // info.style.textAlign = 'center';
       // info.innerHTML = 'Drag to spin the warehouse';
       // container.appendChild(info);

        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, CANVAS_WIDTH / CANVAS_HEIGHT, 1, 1000);
        camera.position.y = 150;
        camera.position.z = 500;

        scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // Warehouse

        var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(Warehouse.length, Warehouse.width, Warehouse.height);

        for (var i = 0; i < geometry.faces.length; i += 2) {
            var hex = Math.random() * 0xffffff;
            geometry.faces[i].color.setHex(hex);
            geometry.faces[i + 1].color.setHex(hex);
        }//end for loop

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, overdraw: 0.5 });
        cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        cube.position.y = 150;
        scene.add(cube);

        //Plane

        var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(200, 200);
        geometry.rotateX(- Math.PI / 2);

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x0e0e0, overdraw: 0.5 });

        plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        scene.add(plane);

        renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
        renderer.setClearColor(0xf0f0f0);
        renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
        renderer.setSize(CANVAS_WIDTH, CANVAS_HEIGHT);
        container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

       // stats = new Stats();
       // container.appendChild(stats.dom);

        document.addEventListener('mousedown', onDocumentMouseDown, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchstart', onDocumentTouchStart, false);
        document.addEventListener('touchmove', onDocumentTouchMove, false);

        window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
    }//end init

    function onWindowResize() {

        windowHalfX = window.innerWidth / 2;
        windowHalfY = window.innerHeight / 2;

        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    }//end on WindowResize

    function onDocumentMouseDown(event) {

        event.preventDefault();

        document.addEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.addEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);

        mouseXOnMouseDown = event.clientX - windowHalfX;
        targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;
    }// end onDocumentMouseDown

    function onDocumentMouseMove(event) {
        mouseX = event.clientX - windowHalfX;

        targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.02;
    }//end onDocumentMouseMove

    function onDocumentMouseUp(event) {
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);

    }//end onDocumentMouseUp

    function onDocumentMouseOut(event) {

        document.removeEventListener(' mousemove', onDocumentMouseMove, false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onDocumentMouseUp, false);
        document.removeEventListener('mouseout', onDocumentMouseOut, false);

    }//end onDocumentMouseOut

    function onDocumentTouchStart(event) {

        if (event.touches.length === 1) {
            event.preventDefault();

            mouseXOnMouseDown = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotationOnMouseDown = targetRotation;

        }//end if
    }//end onDocumentTouchStart

    function onDocumentTouchMove(event) {

        if (event.touches.length === 1) {
            event.preventDefault();

            mouseX = event.touches[0].pageX - windowHalfX;
            targetRotation = targetRotationOnMouseDown + (mouseX - mouseXOnMouseDown) * 0.05;

        }//end if
    }//end onDocumentTouchStart

    function animate() {

        requestAnimationFrame(animate);

       // stats.begin();
        render();
       // stats.end();
    }//end animate

    function render() {

        plane.rotation.y = cube.rotation.y += (targetRotation - cube.rotation.y) * 0.05;
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
    }//end render
    //Save Button


<div class="panel-body" name="All++GROUP++" style="float: left; width: 50%;">
    <form name="myForm">
        <div class="platform-form-group ng-scope group" name="WareHouseInfromation++GROUP++">
            <button class="promptCollapsebutton" type="button" onclick="ToggleGroupVisibility(this)">-</button><b>Warehouse Information</b>
            <!--Grouping for entire prompt-->
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="LOW++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    LOW
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="LOW++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Length of Warehouse ( Lnft ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="LOW" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="WOW++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    WOW
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="WOW++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Width of Warehouse ( Lnft ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="WOW" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="HOW++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    HOW
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="HOW++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Height of Warehouse ( Lnft ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="HOW" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="CBSL++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    CBSL
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="CBSL++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Column Bay Spacing - Length ( Lnft ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="CBSL" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="CBSW++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    CBSW
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="CBSW++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Column Bay Spacing - Width ( Lnft ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="CBSW" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="EXT++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    EXT
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="EXT++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Exterior Construction:
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <select class="auto-style3" name="EXT" oninput="theInputChanged()">
                        <option value="0">No exterior</option>
                        <option value="1">Metal siding</option>
                        <option value="2">Tiltup</option>
                        <option value="3">Concrete block</option>
                        <option value="4">Insulated Panels</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="NDD++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    NDD
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="NDD++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Number of Dock Doors ( Each ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="NDD" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="SOA++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    SOA
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="SOA++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Square Footage of Office Area:
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="SOA" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="platform-form-row form-group" name="NPS++PROMPT++">
                <div class="promptLabel">
                    NPS
                </div>
                <div class="promptDescription" name="CBSW++DESCRIPTION++">
                    Number of Parking Spaces ( Each ):
                </div>
                <div class="promptValue">
                    <input class="auto-style3" max="16" min="1" name="NPS" step="1" type="number">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) Is `CanvasRenderer` a requirement? 2) Rather than creating the geometry with the specified sizes, consider creating a 1x1x1 box, and scaling the sides by the given amounts. I'll take a deeper look later.

Comment: It isn't a requirement it just happened to be what I used.  I have a form that sets a warehouse up based on height width length etc.. So i need to start from nothing on screen to something based off of the input on each part of the form.

Comment: Where are you handling your form submission? Or is the form already populated by the time you reach this code?

Comment: I edited the original post, under save button is the code in my body.  There is no submit. This should update every time a field is filled out.

Answer (score 0):

Simple fix, just created a new function that separates the canvas initialization and the shape formation.  This then updates with a model for the shape.